# Preferred video compression, size and resolution

Tags: video, video-encoding, flv

I'm building a video sharing website for a couple of clients of mine, I've the option of selecting what format, resolution, codecs etc that my clients will use when uploading a video.

The website doesn't need HD videos and they will not be seen on a fullscreen mode, I was going to ask them to upload the videos using:

- as the video codec: H.264
- audio codec: MP3 (with a sampling rate of 44.1kHz )
- FLV as the container

However I don't know what to use as the video bit rate, frame rate and video resolution.
The video should look nice (but not HQ since I've a limited bandwidth) on a youtube like player.

Thanks a bunch,
Ze Maria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use FLV as the container.  Even Adobe says this is a bad idea.  Instead, use MP4.  (Adobe names them F4V, but they are still valid MP4 files.)

If HD is not a requirement, then I'd suggest a video bit rate  between 512kbps and 768kbps.  For audio either 64kbps and 96kbps.